# Connecting Android with Java XMPP Server via FCM

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp

I would like to send data (not notifications!) from an XMPP Server (written in Java) via Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to my Android smartphone and to get then an answer back from Android via FCM to the XMPP server.
I've written a simple Java server and the Android app. My problem is the following: I CAN send data to the phone, i.e. I'll receive the data, but the XMPP server didn't get an answer from the phone. I don't know, if the problem is the Android code or the Java Server code.
If I start the server, it send the data message after the successfully authentication, after then it receives the ACK message from FCM and then ... nothing, instead receiving the answer data message from Android:

```
Nov 03, 2016 1:01:53 PM at.co.michael.SmackCcsClient$LoggingConnectionListener authenticated
INFORMATION: Authenticated.
Nov 03, 2016 1:01:53 PM at.co.michael.SmackCcsClient$3 interceptPacket
INFORMATION: Sent: <message id='0l8n4-2'><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{&quot;collapse_key&quot;:&quot;sample&quot;,&quot;content_available&quot;:true,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;body&quot;:&quot;Hurra&quot;},&quot;time_to_live&quot;:10000,&quot;message_id&quot;:&quot;m-7e78fcf6-c6b2-4c72-a747-03a582d93d0d&quot;,&quot;to&quot;:&quot;myhardcodedregistrationid&quot;,&quot;priority&quot;:&quot;high&quot;}</gcm></message>
Nov 03, 2016 1:01:53 PM at.co.michael.SmackCcsClient$2 processPacket
INFORMATION: Received: <message><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{&quot;message_type&quot;:&quot;ack&quot;,&quot;from&quot;:&quot;myhardcodedregistrationid&quot;,&quot;message_id&quot;:&quot;m-7e78fcf6-c6b2-4c72-a747-03a582d93d0d&quot;}</gcm></message>
Nov 03, 2016 1:01:53 PM at.co.michael.SmackCcsClient handleAckReceipt
INFORMATION: handleAckReceipt() from: myhardcodedregistrationid, messageId: m-7e78fcf6-c6b2-4c72-a747-03a582d93d0d
```

This is my Java server code:

```
package at.co.michael;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketInterceptor;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException.NotConnectedException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.DefaultPacketExtension;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Packet;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.PacketExtension;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.PacketExtensionProvider;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ProviderManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.StringUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

/**
 * Sample Smack implementation of a client for GCM Cloud Connection Server. This
 * code can be run as a standalone CCS client.
 *
 * <p>For illustration purposes only.
 */
public class SmackCcsClient {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SmackCcsClient");

    private static final String GCM_SERVER = "fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com";
    private static final int GCM_PORT = 5235;

    private static final String GCM_ELEMENT_NAME = "gcm";
    private static final String GCM_NAMESPACE = "google:mobile:data";

    static {

        ProviderManager.addExtensionProvider(GCM_ELEMENT_NAME, GCM_NAMESPACE,
            new PacketExtensionProvider() {
                @Override
                public PacketExtension parseExtension(XmlPullParser parser) throws
                        Exception {
                    String json = parser.nextText();
                    return new GcmPacketExtension(json);
                }
            });
    }

    private XMPPConnection connection;

    /**
     * Indicates whether the connection is in draining state, which means that it
     * will not accept any new downstream messages.
     */
    protected volatile boolean connectionDraining = false;

    /**
     * Sends a downstream message to GCM.
     *
     * @return true if the message has been successfully sent.
     */
    public boolean sendDownstreamMessage(String jsonRequest) throws
            NotConnectedException {
        if (!connectionDraining) {
            send(jsonRequest);
            return true;
        }
        logger.info("Dropping downstream message since the connection is draining");
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a random message id to uniquely identify a message.
     *
     * <p>Note: This is generated by a pseudo random number generator for
     * illustration purpose, and is not guaranteed to be unique.
     */
    public String nextMessageId() {
        return "m-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    /**
     * Sends a packet with contents provided.
     */
    protected void send(String jsonRequest) throws NotConnectedException {
        Packet request = new GcmPacketExtension(jsonRequest).toPacket();
        connection.sendPacket(request);
    }

    /**
     * Handles an upstream data message from a device application.
     *
     * <p>This sample echo server sends an echo message back to the device.
     * Subclasses should override this method to properly process upstream messages.
     */
    protected void handleUpstreamMessage(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
        // PackageName of the application that sent this message.
        String category = (String) jsonObject.get("category");
        String from = (String) jsonObject.get("from");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String> payload = (Map<String, String>) jsonObject.get("data");
        payload.put("ECHO", "Application: " + category);

        // Send an ECHO response back
        String echo = createJsonMessage(from, nextMessageId(), payload,
                "echo:CollapseKey", null, false);

        try {
            sendDownstreamMessage(echo);
        } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Not connected anymore, echo message is not sent", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles an ACK.
     *
     * <p>Logs a INFO message, but subclasses could override it to
     * properly handle ACKs.
     */
    protected void handleAckReceipt(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
        String messageId = (String) jsonObject.get("message_id");
        String from = (String) jsonObject.get("from");
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "handleAckReceipt() from: " + from + ", messageId: " + messageId);
    }

    /**
     * Handles a NACK.
     *
     * <p>Logs a INFO message, but subclasses could override it to
     * properly handle NACKs.
     */
    protected void handleNackReceipt(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
        String messageId = (String) jsonObject.get("message_id");
        String from = (String) jsonObject.get("from");
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "handleNackReceipt() from: " + from + ", messageId: " + messageId);
    }

    protected void handleControlMessage(Map<String, Object> jsonObject) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "handleControlMessage(): " + jsonObject);
        String controlType = (String) jsonObject.get("control_type");
        if ("CONNECTION_DRAINING".equals(controlType)) {
            connectionDraining = true;
        } else {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Unrecognized control type: %s. This could happen if "
                    + "new features are " + "added to the CCS protocol.",
                    controlType);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a JSON encoded GCM message.
     *
     * @param to RegistrationId of the target device (Required).
     * @param messageId Unique messageId for which CCS will send an
     *         "ack/nack" (Required).
     * @param payload Message content intended for the application. (Optional).
     * @param collapseKey GCM collapse_key parameter (Optional).
     * @param timeToLive GCM time_to_live parameter (Optional).
     * @param delayWhileIdle GCM delay_while_idle parameter (Optional).
     * @return JSON encoded GCM message.
     */
    public static String createJsonMessage(String to, String messageId,
            Map<String, String> payload, String collapseKey, Long timeToLive,
            Boolean delayWhileIdle) {
        Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        message.put("to", to);
        if (collapseKey != null) {
            message.put("collapse_key", collapseKey);
        }
        if (timeToLive != null) {
            message.put("time_to_live", timeToLive);
        }
        if (delayWhileIdle != null && delayWhileIdle) {
            //message.put("delay_while_idle", true);
        }
      message.put("message_id", messageId);
      message.put("content_available", true);
      message.put("priority", "high");
      //message.put("notification", payload);
      message.put("data", payload);
      System.out.println(JSONValue.toJSONString(message));
      return JSONValue.toJSONString(message);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a JSON encoded ACK message for an upstream message received
     * from an application.
     *
     * @param to RegistrationId of the device who sent the upstream message.
     * @param messageId messageId of the upstream message to be acknowledged to CCS.
     * @return JSON encoded ack.
     */
        protected static String createJsonAck(String to, String messageId) {
        Map<String, Object> message = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        message.put("message_type", "ack");
        message.put("to", to);
        message.put("message_id", messageId);
        return JSONValue.toJSONString(message);
    }

    /**
     * Connects to GCM Cloud Connection Server using the supplied credentials.
     *
     * @param senderId Your GCM project number
     * @param apiKey API Key of your project
     */
    public void connect(String senderId, String apiKey)
            throws XMPPException, IOException, SmackException {
        ConnectionConfiguration config =
                new ConnectionConfiguration(GCM_SERVER, GCM_PORT);
        config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
        config.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
        config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false);
        config.setSendPresence(false);
        config.setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault());

        //config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);

        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
        connection.connect();

        connection.addConnectionListener(new LoggingConnectionListener());

        // Handle incoming packets
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Received: " + packet.toXML());
                Message incomingMessage = (Message) packet;
                GcmPacketExtension gcmPacket =
                        (GcmPacketExtension) incomingMessage
                        .getExtension(GCM_NAMESPACE);
                String json = gcmPacket.getJson();
                try {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    Map<String, Object> jsonObject =
                            (Map<String, Object>) JSONValue
                            .parseWithException(json);

                    // present for "ack"/"nack", null otherwise
                    Object messageType = jsonObject.get("message_type");

                    if (messageType == null) {
                        // Normal upstream data message
                        handleUpstreamMessage(jsonObject);

                        // Send ACK to CCS
                        String messageId = jsonObject.get("message_id").toString();
                        String from = jsonObject.get("from").toString();
                        System.out.println(messageId);
                        System.out.println(from);
                        String ack = createJsonAck(from, messageId);
                        send(ack);
                    } else if ("ack".equals(messageType.toString())) {
                          // Process Ack
                          handleAckReceipt(jsonObject);
                    } else if ("nack".equals(messageType.toString())) {
                          // Process Nack
                          handleNackReceipt(jsonObject);
                    } else if ("control".equals(messageType.toString())) {
                          // Process control message
                          handleControlMessage(jsonObject);
                    } else {
                          logger.log(Level.WARNING,
                                  "Unrecognized message type (%s)",
                                  messageType.toString());
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error parsing JSON " + json, e);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to process packet", e);
                }
            }
        }, new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));

        // Log all outgoing packets
        connection.addPacketInterceptor(new PacketInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void interceptPacket(Packet packet) {
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Sent: {0}", packet.toXML());
            }
        }, new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));

        connection.login(senderId + "@gcm.googleapis.com", apiKey);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String senderId = "mysenderid"; // your GCM sender id
        final String password = "myserverkey";


        SmackCcsClient ccsClient = new SmackCcsClient();

        try {
            ccsClient.connect(senderId, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Send a sample hello downstream message to a device.
        String toRegId = "myhardcodedregistrationid";
        String messageId = ccsClient.nextMessageId();
        Map<String, String> payload = new HashMap<String, String>();
        payload.put("body", "Hurra");
        //payload.put("sound", "default");
        //payload.put("Hello", "World");
        //payload.put("CCS", "Dummy Message");
        //payload.put("EmbeddedMessageId", messageId);
        String collapseKey = "sample";
        Long timeToLive = 10000L;
        String message = createJsonMessage(toRegId, messageId, payload,
                collapseKey, timeToLive, true);

        ccsClient.sendDownstreamMessage(message);

        while (true);
    }

    /**
     * XMPP Packet Extension for GCM Cloud Connection Server.
     */
    private static final class GcmPacketExtension extends DefaultPacketExtension {

        private final String json;

        public GcmPacketExtension(String json) {
            super(GCM_ELEMENT_NAME, GCM_NAMESPACE);
            this.json = json;
        }

        public String getJson() {
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        public String toXML() {
            return String.format("<%s xmlns=\"%s\">%s</%s>",
                    GCM_ELEMENT_NAME, GCM_NAMESPACE,
                    StringUtils.escapeForXML(json), GCM_ELEMENT_NAME);
        }

        public Packet toPacket() {
            Message message = new Message();
            message.addExtension(this);
            return message;
        }
    }

    private static final class LoggingConnectionListener
            implements ConnectionListener {

        @Override
        public void connected(XMPPConnection xmppConnection) {
            logger.info("Connected.");
        }

        @Override
        public void authenticated(XMPPConnection xmppConnection) {
            logger.info("Authenticated.");
        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
            logger.info("Reconnecting..");
        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reconnection failed.. ", e);
        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reconnecting in %d secs", seconds);
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
            logger.info("Connection closed on error.");
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosed() {
            logger.info("Connection closed.");
        }
    }
}
```

My Android app consists of an (empty) MainActivity.java, a MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java and a MyFirebaseMessagingService.java. Furthermore it contains the AndroidManifest.xml and the file google-services.json provides from Google.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="at.co.michael.messaging">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package at.co.michael.messaging;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java:

```
package at.co.michael.messaging;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;


//Class extending FirebaseInstanceIdService
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        //Getting registration token
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        //Displaying token on logcat
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        //You can implement this method to store the token on your server
        //Not required for current project
    }
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
package at.co.michael.messaging;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.media.ToneGenerator;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Displaying data in log
        //It is optional
        Log.d(TAG, "ABCDEFGH");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        //Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            ToneGenerator toneGen1 = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
            toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP, 150);

            String projectId = "myclientid";
            AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();

            FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
            try {
                fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(projectId + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
                        .setMessageId(Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet()))
                        .addData("my_message", "Hello World")
                        //.addData("my_action","SAY_HELLO")
                        .build());
                Log.d(TAG, "Sent...MsgId:" + msgId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "NOT Sent....");
            }

        }

        //Calling method to generate notification
        //sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageSent (String msgId) {
        //super.onMessageSent(msgId);
        Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESSFULLY Sent!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSendError (String msgId, Exception e) {
        //super.onSendError(msgId, e);
        Log.d(TAG, "NOT Sent!");
    }

    /**
     * Method to verify google play services on the device
     * */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Some error?");
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "This device is not supported (Google Play)");
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not directly to answer your question, but are you aware that [Eclipse is no longer officially supported for Android Development](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/193-android/8733-google-drops-support-for-eclipse-its-all-android-studio-now.html). Using Eclipse can prevent the project to quickly creating apps and finding the necessary resources to build a project. To migrate to the Android Studio from Eclipse just follow this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) from Google developers.

Comment: is projectId  in android app your serverId ?